# Replace a node in xml data column in DB2 database

Tags: sql, xml, database, db2

I need to replace particular node in xml stored in DB2 database with another node using SQL query.

e.g.

```
<Data>
   <node1>test</node1>
</Data>
```

After update I need xml as:

```
 <Data>
   <node2>test</node2>
 </Data>
```

Please suggest how can this be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this with below query:

```
update TABLE_NAME
set XML_COLUMN = xmlquery(
  'copy $new := $XML_COLUMN
   modify do rename $new/node1 as "node2" 
   return $new' 
)
```